# Fixed height but responsive images

Tags: css

I have a set of logos of variable size. I've set them all up at the same height of `50px` with a width of `auto`:

```
.img-logo {
   width: auto;
   height: 50px;
}
```

This works fine until the window is resized. When the window is resized, wider logos flow outside of their container.

I would like the logos to shrink to fit their container width. I have tried to achieve this with max-width:

```
.img-logo {
   max-width: 100%;
   width: auto;
   height: 50px;
}
```

This works but the aspect ratio is compromised due to the height property remaining 50px.

Any ideas?

Comment: please crop the images as to aspect radio size

Comment: Try min-height for that.

Answer (score 1):

With a fixed `height` and variable `width` either of the below can happen.

1. The `img` gets stretched to accommodate the variable width and skew the aspect ratio.
2. The `img` gets cropped (`overflow:hidden`) by the parent but the aspect ration is kept intact.

So you can make the `img` responsive too. But then it wont have the constant height, while keeping the aspect ratio intact.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to keep its size when the window is too small and you didn't want to change ths size of image. Why not try `@media`,which can provide different css styles in different conditions.